# How to create a profile page in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress

I can't find a way to create a front-end profile page for all users under Wordpress Multisite Network. I also wanted the profile page to be on the main site and not on sub-sites if possible. I don't want to use any social network plugins like buddypress.. I just want to create a page like `http://mainsite.com/profile/username`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you might check out Buddypress which is a social layer on top of Wordpress and is able to do what you need (i.e. something like `http://mainsite.com/profile/username`).

Link: http://buddypress.org/

More specifically, in Buddypress the default behaviour is `http://mainsite.com/members/username`

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have edited the question and that you are looking for a way to accomplish this without any plugin. There are a series of tags in Wordpress to show the author's data. So basically you could create a page and then use the_author_meta tags. For example the following code echoes the first and last name of a user whose name is stored in `$userID`:

```
<?php 
$pagename = $userID;
echo the_author_meta(user_firstname, $userID ); 
echo the_author_meta(user_lastname, $userID ); 
?>
```

Please note that the variable `$pagename` is empty in case you use a static page as home page, but it is not your case.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta